# Receive and interpret different types of JSON objects from single servlet

Tags: java, json

I have several types of JSON readings that I want to fetch from a single URL servlet. For example, ReadingType1, ReadingType2, ReadingType3 ... each has its own structure.

However, according to my code, when I parse the JSON string and convert it into a Java object, I have to specify the type of object to cast it to. There is no mechanism to check the structure of JSON in order to determine what type of object to cast it to first.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String line = null;
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Reading reading = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), Reading.class);
}
```

Note the last line specifies that the type is Reading when converting it into an object.

How do you check the structure of the JSON input before determining what object it is?

E.g.

```
if (JSON has structure1) { reading = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), ReadingType1.class); }

else if (JSON has structure2) { reading = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), ReadingType2.class); }

else if (JSON has structure3) { reading = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), ReadingType3.class); }
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use a JSON parser to read the class Type Out of the JSON? Of course you'd have to include the Type of class in the JSON first, type: 1

Comment: Preferably you should different urls for different object. (Correct Rest usage).  If not then you could either embed the class type and test `String.contains ("classtype=\"ReadingType1\"");` or use try catch blocks

Answer (score 0):

I added a string parameter to my JSON which has the class name in it.

```
// sample JSON
{
    "factType":"SomeFact",
    "someParam":"value"
}

package com.acme.services;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

/**
 * service that maps JSON to class
 * 
 * @author gal.nitzan.1
 *
 */

@Service
public class MapperService {
    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public MapperService() {
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public Class mapToClass(String jsonString) throws IllegalFactPayloadException {
        if (jsonString == null || jsonString.length() == 0) {
            throw new IllegalFactPayloadException("jsonString can not be null or empty.");
        }

        Class clazz = null;
        ObjectNode node = null;

        try {
            node = mapper.readValue(jsonString, ObjectNode.class);
        }
        catch (JsonParseException e) {
            throw new IllegalFactPayloadException(e);
        }
        catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            throw new IllegalFactPayloadException(e);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalFactPayloadException(e);
        }

        if (node.has("factType")) {
            try {
                clazz = Class.forName("com.acme.entities." + node.get("factType").asText());
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new IllegalFactPayloadException(e);
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalFactPayloadException("jsonString is missing factType attribute.");
        }

        return clazz;
    }
}
```

HTH,
Gal